# neo4j - standalone server or embedded for this case?

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-theory

I currently have a Java application that updates a neo4j database every day.

I then have another application that queries the database using traversals by creating an embedded database with the same storage path.

How should I go about keeping the server running and directing the queries at the already running instance every time the querying java application runs? I'm unsure how to do this without creating an embedded server instance every time.

I can keep my current approach, the problem is it has to load the database every single time a user makes a request for a query and this is expensive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run server on top of an embedded database: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-embedded.html

So you can keep your embedded app running and import the data using a timer-task and at the same time offer the server's web-ui.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it expensive, but if I understood your application concept correctly, you have a potential lock store error.

If your updating application is doing something in the database, and thus has an instance of the embedded database running, and at the same time your other application is trying to make an instance of the embedded database to perform a query, you'd run into a lock store.

I don't know if you have taken any precautions to prevent this, or if you've just been lucky so far that these actions have not occured simultaneously, but I would look into it.

Comment: I have a tomcat context variable which holds the indexes to the database. I'm trying to work out the best way to handle updates. I was thinking of simply closing the application for maintenance whilst the update runs, creating a new database then deleting the old and replacing with the new, and open the application again. It's easier for me to create a whole new database for updates than run through every node checking for changes.